# Quais são as sintaxes do laço for em java?

Tags: java, sintaxe

Olá!

Todos que programam em Java já devem estar cansados de utilizar laços de repetição `for`, que quase sempre tem uma sintaxe parecida com essa:

```
for (int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
    ...
}
```

Eu estava analisando alguns códigos e me deparei com uma sintaxe diferente:

```
for (String novaString : arrayDeStrings) {
    ...
{
```

Pelo que eu entendi, o laço irá repetir X vezes, onde X é igual ao tamanho do *array* de *strings* (`arrayDeStrings.length`) e a cada repetição, `novaString` vai receber o conteúdo de uma das *strings* do `arrayDeStrings`.

**Dúvidas**

É assim mesmo que essa segunda sintaxe apresentada funciona? Existem outras sintaxes além das citadas nessa pergunta? Se sim, como elas funcionam?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Essa é uma modalidade de loop equivalente ao *for ... each* de outras linguagens.

Como você suspeitou, ele itera o array `arrayDeStrings`, pegando sequencialmente cada um de seus ítens e devolvendo em `novaString`, executando a parte interior do loop com o valor de cada ítem respectivamente.

Imagine a seguinte *array* de *Strings*:

```
String[] arrayDeStrings = { "Banana", "Maçã", "Pera" };
```

Com essa array, fazendo tanto assim:

```
// Sintaxe foreach
for (String novaString : arrayDeStrings) {
   System.out.println( novaString );
}
```

quanto assim:

```
// Sintaxe for com iterador
for (Iterator<String> i = arrayDeStrings.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
   String novaString = i.next();
   System.out.println( novaString );
}
```

ou assim:

```
// Sintaxe for convencional
for(int i = 0; i < arrayDeStrings.length; i++) {
   System.out.println( arrayDeStrings[i] );
}
```

Você terá o resultado esperado:

```
Banana
Maçã
Pera
```

> Notar que o `foreach` é apenas um *syntax-sugar*, pois conforme comentário pertinente do [@mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/215/mgibsonbr), ele será transformado em um dos dois códigos que foram expostos em seguida, dependendo de se tratar de um *Iterable* ou *Array* no parâmetro.

Comment: Certo, então é assim mesmo que ele funciona. Existem outros parecidos?

Comment: @Deyel por coincidência, acabei de postar.

Comment: Poxa, bacana! Vou esperar um tempo antes de dar a melhor resposta, pra ver se outras pessoas conhecem outras sintaxes...

Comment: @Deyel não tenha pressa, com certeza tem um pessoal bom em Java aqui (e java não é bem minha praia). Podem aparecer coisas bem mais elaboradas!

Comment: pois é, também não sou pró em java haha. De qualquer forma obrigado pelo esclarecimento!

Comment: +1 e gostaria de acrescentar que o segundo código (usando `Iterator`) é basicamente o que o compilador vai gerar quando encontra o for..in aplicado a um [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) e - segundo [essa resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3912785/520779) - o segundo código é o que ele vai gerar quando aplicado a um array.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Então quer dizer que a primeira sintaxe apresentada na resposta só foi criada para facilitar o uso da segunda? (mascarar a complexidade)

Comment: @Deyel Sim, da segunda e da terceira. Que eu saiba, é só um "açúcar sintático" mesmo, não acrescenta nada que não pudesse ser feito sem ela. Mas com certeza ajuda bastante na clareza e concisão do código.

Comment: Pessoalmente acho que o segundo caso é melhor expressado com um `while` e não um `for`. E não, não há outras sintaxes de `for`, se é isso que quer saber.

Comment: @Piovezan concordo, mas como a pergunta era sobre sintaxes de For, fiquei dentro do "tema" :)

Answer (score 3):

Este tipo de construção teve início com o Java 5. Ele é chamado de `for-each` e faz exatamente isto: para cada elemento dado no *loop* do `for`, executa um ou mais comandos.

Com ele a leitura do código fica mais fácil, e internamente ele é compilado para os mesmos `bytecodes` que o `for` ou o `while` correspondentes fariam.

Ele pode ser usado em *arrays*, *Collections* e qualquer outra construção que implemente uma interface *Iterable*.

Existem situações onde você não poderá usar este `for`:

- para atualizar valores da *Array*: ele só lê os valores do array, você não consegue usar este `for` para atualizar os seus valores. Por exemplo, o código abaixo é *inválido*:

```
for (String novaString : arrayDeStrings) {     
 novaString = "banana";     
}
```

- para percorrer duas estruturas ao mesmo tempo: o `for` percorre apenas uma estrutura. Não existe uma construção deste `for` que permita percorrer duas arrays comparando os seus valores, por exemplo.