# Contador do laço não está incrementando

Tags: java, java-ee

Estou tendo uma dificuldade em encontrar o erro em uma lógica que utilizo o for para percorrer um arraylist.

```
  List<Caneta> canetas = new ArrayList<>(); 
  canetas.add(c1);
  canetas.add(c2);

  System.out.print(Arrays.toString(canetas.toArray()));

  for (Caneta caneta : canetas) {
    int x = 0;
    System.out.printf(canetas.get(x).getModelo());
    x++; 
  }
```

O sout me retorna a mesma resposta, como se o x não tivesse se autoincrementado, alguém poderia me explicar o problema?
Grato.

Comment: Mostre o código da criação do `c1` e `c2`

Comment: Você deve declarar o `x` fora do loop for, do jeito que tá ele é zerado a cada iteração

Comment: Para percorrer a lista com for each não é necessário contador, a cada laço o objeto já é incrementado. Na tradução for each é 'para cada'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `x` está sendo inicializado dentro do `foreach`. Desta forma, a cada iteração (*loop*) ele é inicializado com o valor 0.

A solução seria declarar o `x` fora do *loop*.

```
int x = 0;
for (Caneta caneta : canetas) {
    System.out.printf(canetas.get(x).getModelo());
    x++; 
}
```

Apesar do código acima estar certo, ele não faz muito sentido. O `foreach` é usado para "passar" por todos os elementos de uma coleção e, a cada *loop*, alimentar a variável (`caneta`, no caso) com um item da lista.

Então, se você precisa usar o `get(x)`, seria melhor usar um `for`.

```
for(int x = 0; i < canetas.size(), x++) {
    System.out.printf(canetas.get(x).getModelo());
}
```

Ou, se quiser continuar usando o "`foreach`", deveria fazer assim

```
for(Caneta caneta : canetas){
     System.out.printf(caneta.getModelo());
}
```

Talvez você se interesse por ler esta pergunta: [Quais são as sintaxes do laço for em java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11078/18246)

Answer (score 1):

Tenta desta forma:

```
  List<Caneta> canetas = new ArrayList<>(); 
  canetas.add(c1);
  canetas.add(c2);

  System.out.print(Arrays.toString(canetas.toArray()));

  for (Caneta caneta : canetas) {
    System.out.printf(caneta.getModelo());
  }
```

Comment: Apesar de você ter utilizado de fato o foreach, você manteve aquele x do mesmo jeito. Seria bom dar uma explicação mínima sobre o funcionamento do laço foreach para o OP

Comment: Eu posso ter mantido, mas o meu vai percorrer a lista.